# How to fetch server-side sqlite database to user-side in order to make use of "sql.js"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite

I found this tool called "sql.js" that can access sqlite database directly from javascript. But in order to use it, the user-side has to have the sqlite database file first. In my situation, the database is maintained at the server-side. So here is my question: how do I move the sqlite database file from the server-side to the user-side-javascript so that user-side can make use of this "sql.js" to access the database? Is it possible to do in an Ajax call? Any sample code would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Think this [example](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/blob/master/README.md#loading-a-database-from-a-server) in the docs wasn't added at the time the question was asked:

```
<script src='js/sql.js'></script>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/path/to/database.sqlite', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
  var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
  var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM my_table");
  // contents is now [{columns:['col1','col2',...], values:[[first row], [second row], ...]}]
};
  xhr.send();
</script>
```

Bear in mind that if your database is large, SQL.js probably isn't suitable.

(Partly because you'll have to transfer the database to the user, and partly because [SQL.js is memory hungry](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/wiki/FAQ), so you may be better running the queries on the server anyway.)